# Billiards Balls Stuck Inside Each other

Tags: java, processing, collision

I am designing a billiards game for my Java class. I am having an issue with the billiard balls collisions. The balls hit into each other and occasionally slide into each other, becoming stuck. I can't seem to identify the cause of this error. I was hoping somebody could assist me in finding the cause of the issue. My code is below. Thank You.

```
    float cueX = 200;
    float cueY = 225;
    float cueDeltaX;
    float cueDeltaY;
    float ballWidth = 25;
    float score = 0;

    Billiards[] billiards = new Billiards[3];

    void setup()
    {
      size (850, 450);
      background(0);
      fill(#29B748);
      rect(0, 0, 599, 599);
      billiards[0] = new Billiards(600, 225, 0, 0, false, "", 0);
      billiards[1] = new Billiards(625, 211, 0, 0, false, "", 1);
      billiards[2] = new Billiards(625, 239, 0, 0, false, "", 2);
      //billiards[3] = new Billiards(625, 250, 0, 0, false, "", 2);
    }

    void draw()
    { 
      background(0);
      fill(#FFFFFF);
      stroke(#A6A7A6);
      text("DeltaX: " + cueDeltaX + "  Delta Y: " + cueDeltaY, 20, 20);
      text(score, 500, 20);
      fill(#29B748);
      rect(25, 25, 799, 399);
      poolCueLines();
      drawCue();
      moveCue();
      cueBounce();
      cueFriction();

      drawBilliards();
      billiards[0].collision();
      billiards[0].moveBall();
      billiards[0].billiardBounce();
      billiards[0].billiardFriction();

      billiards[1].collision();
      billiards[1].moveBall();
      billiards[1].billiardBounce();
      billiards[1].billiardFriction();

      billiards[2].collision();
      billiards[2].moveBall();
      billiards[2].billiardBounce();
      billiards[2].billiardFriction();
    }

    void poolCueLines() {
      if (mousePressed)
      {
        stroke(#FFFFFF);
        line(cueX, cueY, mouseX, mouseY);
      }
    }

    void mouseReleased()
    {
      cueDeltaX = (cueX - mouseX)/50;
      cueDeltaY = (cueY - mouseY)/50;
    }

    void drawCue() {
      noStroke();
      fill(0);
      fill(#FFFFFF);
      stroke(#A6A7A6);
      ellipse(cueX, cueY, ballWidth, ballWidth);
      noFill();
    }

    void moveCue() {
      cueX += cueDeltaX;
      cueY += cueDeltaY;
    }

    void cueBounce() {
      if (cueX > width-25-ballWidth/2 || cueX < 25 + ballWidth/ 2) {
        cueDeltaX = -cueDeltaX;
        cueDeltaX = cueDeltaX * 0.6;
        if (cueX < 25+ ballWidth/2) {
          cueX = 26 + ballWidth/2;
        } else {
          cueX = width-26-ballWidth/2;
        }
      }

      if (cueY > height-25-ballWidth/2 || cueY < 25 + ballWidth/ 2) {
        cueDeltaY = -cueDeltaY;
        cueDeltaY = cueDeltaY * 0.6;
        if (cueY < 25+ ballWidth/2) {
          cueY = 26 + ballWidth/2;
        } else {
          cueY = height-26-ballWidth/2;
        }
      }
    }

    void drawBilliards() {

      //Yellow Ball 1
      fill(#ffff00);
      stroke(#A6A7A6);
      ellipse(billiards[0].ballXpos, billiards[0].ballYpos, ballWidth, ballWidth);

      //Blue 2
      fill(#000099);
      stroke(#A6A7A6);
      ellipse(billiards[1].ballXpos, billiards[1].ballYpos, ballWidth, ballWidth);

      //Red 3
      fill(#ff0000);
      stroke(#A6A7A6);
      ellipse(billiards[2].ballXpos, billiards[2].ballYpos, ballWidth, ballWidth);
    }

    void cueFriction() {
      cueDeltaX = cueDeltaX * 0.995;
      cueDeltaY = cueDeltaY * 0.995;
    }

    class Billiards
    {
      float ballXpos;
      float ballYpos;
      float deltaXball;
      float deltaYball;
      int billiardsNum;

      Billiards(float tempXpos, float tempYpos, float deltaXbill, float deltaYbill, boolean stripe, String stripeColor, int billiardNum) {
        ballXpos = tempXpos;
        ballYpos = tempYpos;
        deltaXball = deltaXbill;
        deltaYball = deltaYbill;
        billiardsNum = billiardNum;
      }

      void collision() {
        if (cueX > ballXpos-ballWidth && cueX < ballXpos+ballWidth) {
          if (cueY < ballYpos+ballWidth && cueY > ballYpos-ballWidth) {
            cueDeltaX = -cueDeltaX * 0.8;
            deltaXball = -cueDeltaX * 0.6;
            cueDeltaY = -cueDeltaY * 0.8;
            deltaYball = -cueDeltaY * 0.6;
          }
        }

        int ballNum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < 3; i++) {
          if (billiards[ballNum].ballXpos > ballXpos-ballWidth && billiards[ballNum].ballXpos < ballXpos+ballWidth) {
            if (billiards[ballNum].ballYpos < ballYpos+ballWidth && billiards[ballNum].ballYpos > ballYpos-ballWidth) {
              if (billiardsNum == ballNum) {
              } else {
                //if (billiards[ballNum].deltaXball < 0.2 || billiards[ballNum].deltaYball < 0.2) {
                  if (deltaXball > 0){
                   billiards[ballNum].ballXpos += -3;
                  }else if (deltaXball < 0){
                   billiards[ballNum].ballXpos += 3;
                  }

                  if (deltaYball > 0){
                   billiards[ballNum].ballXpos += -3;
                  }else if (deltaYball < 0){
                   billiards[ballNum].ballXpos += 3;
                  }
                  billiards[ballNum].deltaXball = -billiards[ballNum].deltaXball * 0.8;
                  deltaXball = -billiards[ballNum].deltaXball * 0.6;
                  billiards[ballNum].deltaYball = -billiards[ballNum].deltaYball * 0.8;
                  deltaYball = -billiards[ballNum].deltaYball * 0.6;
                //}
                //} else {
                //  billiards[ballNum].deltaXball = -billiards[ballNum].deltaXball * 0.8;
                //  deltaXball = -billiards[ballNum].deltaXball * 0.6;
                //  billiards[ballNum].deltaYball = -billiards[ballNum].deltaYball * 0.8;
                //  deltaYball = -billiards[ballNum].deltaYball * 0.6;
                //}
              }
            }
          }
          ballNum += 1;
        }
      }

      void moveBall() {
        ballXpos += deltaXball;
        ballYpos += deltaYball;
      }

      void billiardBounce() {
        if (ballXpos > width-25-ballWidth/2 || ballXpos < 25 + ballWidth/ 2) {
          deltaXball = -deltaXball;
          deltaXball = deltaXball * 0.6;
          if (ballXpos < 25+ ballWidth/2) {
            ballXpos = 26 + ballWidth/2;
          } else {
            ballXpos = width-26-ballWidth/2;
          }
        }

        if (ballYpos > height-25-ballWidth/2 || ballYpos < 25 + ballWidth/ 2) {
          deltaYball = -deltaYball;
          deltaYball = deltaYball * 0.6;
          if (ballYpos < 25+ ballWidth/2) {
            ballYpos = 26 + ballWidth/2;
          } else {
            ballYpos = height-26-ballWidth/2;
          }
        }
      }

      void billiardFriction() {
        deltaXball = deltaXball * 0.995;
        deltaYball = deltaYball * 0.995;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Please supply a driver that reproduces the problem, and applicable tracing output on the problematic objects.  There should be at least some print statements here to find out what's happening, if not precisely how things go wrong.

Comment: @Prune While I agree that this is a bit too much code, note that this is [tag:processing], not Java. This class is the driver, since Processing automatically calls certain functions for you. It doesn't have a `main()` method like Java does.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is in your collision code. You've got a lot of magic hard-coded numbers in there, and zero comments describing what they're for. That's going to make this very hard to debug, which makes it hard to help you.

But one thing that jumps out to me is that you're handling collision separately from movement. This might be okay, but with how you're doing it, you can get yourself in this situation:

- Imagine Ball A being between Ball B and Ball C.
- Ball A is moving to the right.
- You check Ball A's collision, and it collides with Ball B. Now you tell Ball A to start moving left.
- You then move Ball A to the left, **but you don't check whether that will result in a collision.** So now Ball A and Ball C are colliding.
- Ball C was moving to the right, but then you check its collision. Sure enough it's colliding with Ball A, so you tell it to start moving to the left.
- Now Ball A and Ball C are both moving to the left, even though they're colliding.

You might want to go through and add comments until you understand exactly what your code is doing. But honestly, this isn't exactly an easy problem. You might be better off starting over with a blank sketch and starting with something simpler. Try to narrow your problem down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Instead of posting your entire sketch, just get it narrowed down to a specific case with two circles colliding using hard-coded values instead of user input.

You also might want to take a look at the CircleCollision example that comes with the Processing editor. Just go to File -> Examples -> Topics -> Motion -> CircleCollision, and you'll see a sketch that shows an example of handling circle collisions.

Here is the collision code from that example:

```
void checkCollision(Ball other) {

    // get distances between the balls components
    PVector bVect = PVector.sub(other.position, position);

    // calculate magnitude of the vector separating the balls
    float bVectMag = bVect.mag();

    if (bVectMag < r + other.r) {
      // get angle of bVect
      float theta  = bVect.heading();
      // precalculate trig values
      float sine = sin(theta);
      float cosine = cos(theta);

      /* bTemp will hold rotated ball positions. You 
       just need to worry about bTemp[1] position*/
      PVector[] bTemp = {
        new PVector(), new PVector()
        };

        /* this ball's position is relative to the other
         so you can use the vector between them (bVect) as the 
         reference point in the rotation expressions.
         bTemp[0].position.x and bTemp[0].position.y will initialize
         automatically to 0.0, which is what you want
         since b[1] will rotate around b[0] */
        bTemp[1].x  = cosine * bVect.x + sine * bVect.y;
      bTemp[1].y  = cosine * bVect.y - sine * bVect.x;

      // rotate Temporary velocities
      PVector[] vTemp = {
        new PVector(), new PVector()
        };

        vTemp[0].x  = cosine * velocity.x + sine * velocity.y;
      vTemp[0].y  = cosine * velocity.y - sine * velocity.x;
      vTemp[1].x  = cosine * other.velocity.x + sine * other.velocity.y;
      vTemp[1].y  = cosine * other.velocity.y - sine * other.velocity.x;

      /* Now that velocities are rotated, you can use 1D
       conservation of momentum equations to calculate 
       the final velocity along the x-axis. */
      PVector[] vFinal = {  
        new PVector(), new PVector()
        };

      // final rotated velocity for b[0]
      vFinal[0].x = ((m - other.m) * vTemp[0].x + 2 * other.m * vTemp[1].x) / (m + other.m);
      vFinal[0].y = vTemp[0].y;

      // final rotated velocity for b[0]
      vFinal[1].x = ((other.m - m) * vTemp[1].x + 2 * m * vTemp[0].x) / (m + other.m);
      vFinal[1].y = vTemp[1].y;

      // hack to avoid clumping
      bTemp[0].x += vFinal[0].x;
      bTemp[1].x += vFinal[1].x;

      /* Rotate ball positions and velocities back
       Reverse signs in trig expressions to rotate 
       in the opposite direction */
      // rotate balls
      PVector[] bFinal = { 
        new PVector(), new PVector()
        };

      bFinal[0].x = cosine * bTemp[0].x - sine * bTemp[0].y;
      bFinal[0].y = cosine * bTemp[0].y + sine * bTemp[0].x;
      bFinal[1].x = cosine * bTemp[1].x - sine * bTemp[1].y;
      bFinal[1].y = cosine * bTemp[1].y + sine * bTemp[1].x;

      // update balls to screen position
      other.position.x = position.x + bFinal[1].x;
      other.position.y = position.y + bFinal[1].y;

      position.add(bFinal[0]);

      // update velocities
      velocity.x = cosine * vFinal[0].x - sine * vFinal[0].y;
      velocity.y = cosine * vFinal[0].y + sine * vFinal[0].x;
      other.velocity.x = cosine * vFinal[1].x - sine * vFinal[1].y;
      other.velocity.y = cosine * vFinal[1].y + sine * vFinal[1].x;
    }
  }
```

You can also view web-based versions of the above example:

- [Circle Collision](https://www.processing.org/examples/circlecollision.html)
- [Bouncy Bubbles](https://www.processing.org/examples/bouncybubbles.html)